# How to get Licurl.lib/libcurl.dll (curllib.dll/curllib.lib) vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl

I downloaded the latest version of curl. Now I want it to work on my visual studio project (2015). I need the libraries to get it to run, but the libraries are not included in the zip file I downloaded from the official website. Any suggestions?

(using visual studio 2015, windows 8 64 bit, c++, targeting a win64 programm)

Comment: I am not sure if this question is duplicate @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: You probably need to download the [libcurl source](http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.44.0.zip) and build it on your system first.

Comment: How do I build it? What kind of filetype do I have to look for in the curl folder? @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: [Here are some instructions](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) what is required to build it on a windows environment.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I guess on your link i have to do "OTHER MSVC IDEs" since I am an vc++ projects.. could you explain me: "
   If you use VC++, Borland or similar compilers. Include all lib source
   files in a static lib "project" (all .c and .h files that is). 
   (you should name it libcurl or similar)
 
   Make the sources in the src/ drawer be a "win32 console application"
   project. Name it curl." I dont really understand what they need me to do!

Comment: Well, if you need help about basics, how to create libraries and link them with your toolchain, that's going way too broad to explain all here. Please do some research on your own. I'm not an expert for libcurl in particular anyways.

Comment: okay, thank you though! @πάντα ῥεῖ